# div with 100% height behaviour on scrolling body

Tags: html, css

I'm having a simple div with a height of `100%`

```
#stripe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
```

when I'm adjusting the browser height, it always goes from top to bottom as expected.
Problem is when the body height has a scroll due to its content, and I'm scrolling down, the div ends.

Is it possible to stop this behaviour and make the div always `height: 100%` on scrolling with css only.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y39Lymow/17/)

Comment: It's to do with positioning, setting position relative seemed to solve the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/y39Lymow/19/

Comment: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y39Lymow/21/) What about using `position: absolute;` with `<body>` tag :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `position: absolute;` with your `<body>` tag. - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y39Lymow/21/)

```
body {
    height: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
}

#stripe {
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove 'position: absolute;' and change `position:relative`

```
#stripe {
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 100px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y39Lymow/20/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position: absolute;` and change `left` to `margin-left`

```
#stripe {
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

#### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y39Lymow/18/)

Comment: yeah that works, problem: In my case it isn't that simple that I just have one stripe. I need the `#stripe` to be positioned absolute to place it above the rest of my content. If its relative, it moves all my content away, and ends in the middle of the scroll anyways.